# Simultaneous linear two variable congruences

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck with this system of linear congruences and could use some guidance as to what I'm doing wrong. This is what I've tried:
I have a system of linear congruences:
12x+4y≡16(mod 174)
9x+9y≡27(mod 174)
Now, avoiding non-regular transformations, I do as following:
-I add second congruence multiplied by -1 to the first one
-then first one multiplied by -3 to the second one
And I get:
3x-5y≡-11(mod 174)
24y≡60(mod 174)
I solve the second one as a Diophantine equation and get y≡17(mod 29) as a solution.
I write y as y=17+29t and plunge it back into the first equation and get:
3x-5(17+29t)≡-11(mod 174)
3x≡74+145 t(mod 174)
For this congruence to be solvable, 74+145t has to be divisible by 3. Since that is not obvious (at least to me), I write: 74+145t=3s
Then I try solving that equation for s and t and I get:
t=-74-3p
s=-3552-145p
Now I tried plunging this t I got back into 74+145t and after limiting it between 0 and 174 I get t=679,t=676,t=673,t=670
I plunge t=679 back into 3x+174k=74+145t and get x≡0(mod 58)

These solutions however make no sense when I check them.
I am sorry if this question is too simple or a mistake I'm making is obvious, but I tried solving this in so many ways, and neither produced correct solutions. (I did get few correct solutions for x and y, along with too many excess solutions(because I used non-regular transformations I guess).

Comment: Look at this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1557537/solving-a-system-of-linear-congruences-with-two-variables

Comment: @Raffaele Thank you, that was very helpful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach in solving for $y$ was right, but got it wrong with $x$; you could reduce them all to modulo $29$ to obtain
$$2x+20y\equiv 22\mod 29\,,$$
$$16x+16y\equiv 19\mod 29\,.$$
Solving these gives us
$$x\equiv 15\mod 29\,,$$
$$ y\equiv 17\mod 29\,.$$
You then extend to the possible solutions modulo $174$:
$$x\equiv 15,44,73,102,131,160\mod 174\,,$$
$$y\equiv 17,46, 75,104,133,162\mod 174\,.$$
Recognizing that the first equation demands that $y\equiv 1\mod 3$, we either have $y\equiv 46~or~133\mod 174$; now, subtracting the second equation from the first gives
$$3x\equiv 5y-11 \mod174\,.$$
Solving for $x$ using the two values of $y$ gives us the respective solution $x\equiv 15~or~44\mod 58$; thus, the system has solutions
$$(x,y)\in\left\lbrace(15,46)\,,(73,46)\,,(131,46)\,,(44,133)\,,(102,133)\,,(160,133)\right\rbrace\,.$$

Comment: No, actual solutions are $$
\begin{array}{rr}
 15 & 46 \\
 44 & 133 \\
 73 & 46 \\
 102 & 133 \\
 131 & 46 \\
 160 & 133 \\
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Oh, so that means I messed up the place for $46$ and $133$, right? I’d check (but if you’ve double-checked, then that’s awesome).

Comment: No double check. I found them with brute force :)

Comment: You’re right, I wrote backwards the last line _respective $x\equiv 44~or~15\mod 58$_ . It should have been the reverse—that is $x\equiv 15~or~44\mod 58$ instead. I have now fixed the solutions appropriately. Thanks!

Comment: @JackLeGrüß Thank you!